# Using @synchronized(self) { ... } in class-function

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Accidentally I have been using a `@synchronized` block with the semaphore `self` in a class method.

```
+(void)someFunction {
    @synchronized(self) {
         /* some code */
    }
}
```

It seems to be valid code, at least the compiler does not give me any bad feedback. My question is: what is `self` here? As far as I can tell the `@synchronized` block didn't work, but it didn't crash either.

I'm just asking out of curiousity.

Comment: I have discussed the same thing some time back in my blog [here](http://allforios.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/self-in-static-method-is-objective-c-a-sane-language/). Perhaps have a look at it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`self` in this instance refers to the class, instead of an instance. In ObjC, classes are themselves objects.

Comment: If a class is an object, what is it an instance of?

Comment: I thinks it's an instance of the class "Class". [someNSObject class] is documented as +(Class)class

Comment: The class object is an instance of the meta-class, which the ObjC runtime creates automatically. A class's "class methods" are really just instance methods on the meta-class, which is why the class object responds to all of those methods.

Comment: The object passed to the @synchronized directive is a unique identifier used to distinguish the protected block. If you execute the preceding method in two different threads, passing a different object for the anObj parameter on each thread, each would take its lock and continue processing without being blocked by the other. If you pass the same object in both cases, however, one of the threads would acquire the lock first and the other would block until the first thread completed the critical section

Answer (score 4):

`self` in this context is the class itself, it's perfectly fine to use `@synchronized` in a class function since they are also Objective-C objects.

Comment: so it would be like [TheClass class]?

Answer (score 3):

The `@synchronized` syntax is a compiler extension for mutex implementation. I assume you understood [what it does](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html). The compiler will translate it into something else, supposedly something similar to [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) because it's less CPU intensive. Locks need to be tracked. The implementation will use an object to record the state of the lock, to keep its integrity (i.e. a lock shouldn't be acquired twice, or unlocked twice).

In `@synchronized(self)`, the object doesn't have to be `self`. It could be any objective-c object. Note that a single `@synchronized` block usually does nothing (when you mentioned it's not working, it's actually behaving correctly). But when you have two `@synchronized` blocks on the **same object**, only one block will be executed at the same time, the other block would have to wait for the lock to be unlocked (i.e. the first block finishes). This helps to keep things synchronized as in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Seems like it'd be a lot more useful to look at the [ObjC docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocThreading.html) on this syntax than the Java docs.

Answer (score 0):

In a class method `self` is the class that the method is being called on. For example you can call other class methods of the same class using `self`. `[MyClass someFunction]` and `[self someFunction]` would be the equivalent to recursively calling `someFunction`. The `@synchronized` block I am sure worked as it was supposed to.